# How to calling another rest API controller that stores information directly from inside another rest API controller?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

How would I go about modifying existing code to call other controllers stored dictionary information? (without recalling the db multiple times, but just once at the start of the rest api's life).

Atm (I think) am storing the information in a dictionary (PipeMaterials) correctly. Now I'm lost on how to go about getting the information out to other controller.

[Controller storing information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxTAb.png)

[Controller wanting to consume information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCzub.png)

Storing

```
public class MaterialsController : ControllerBase
{
    public Dictionary<int, Materials> PipeMaterials;
    public Dictionary<int, Rank> Ranks;
    public Dictionary<int, Sumps> Sumps;

    private readonly UMMClient23Context _context;

    public MaterialsController(UMMClient23Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
        LoadMaterials();
    }

    public void LoadMaterials()
    {
        PipeMaterials = new Dictionary<int, Materials>();
        Task<MaterialsObjects> task = GetMaterials();
        var result = task.Result;
        foreach (var item in result.Ummmaterials)
        {
            if (!PipeMaterials.TryAdd(item.MaterialsId, item))
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("Could not load material: " + item.MaterialsName);
            }
        }
    }

    // GET: api/Materials
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<MaterialsObjects> GetMaterials()
    {
        MaterialsObjects returnable = new MaterialsObjects();
        returnable.Ummmaterials = await _context.Materials.ToListAsync();
        return returnable;
    }

    // GET: api/MaterialDescription/5
    [HttpGet("{materialsId}")]
    public string GetMaterialDescription(int materialsId)
    {
        Materials item;
        if (PipeMaterials.TryGetValue(materialsId, out item))
        {
            return item.MaterialsName;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
        //var materials = _context.Materials
        //    .Where(m=> m.MaterialsId == materialsId)
        //    .Select(m => m.MaterialsName)
        //    .FirstOrDefault();

    }
```

Consuming

```
public class PipeController : ControllerBase
{
    MaterialsController materialsController;

    UMMDBHelper uMMDBHelper;
    private readonly UMMClient23Context _context;

    public PipeController(UMMClient23Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
        uMMDBHelper = new UMMDBHelper(context);
    }

    //GET: api/Pipe
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Data>>> Get(string value)
    {
        return await _context.Data.ToListAsync();
    }


    // GET: api/Pipe/{assestNumber}
    [HttpGet("{assetNumber}")] // Make return into Object
    public PipeListObject GetPipe(string assetNumber)
    {

        PipeListObject returnable = new PipeListObject();
        Pipe Pipe = uMMDBHelper.GetPipe(assetNumber);
        returnable.UmmPipes.Add(Pipe); 
        return returnable;
    }


    //GET: api/PipeMaterial/{materialId}
    [HttpGet("{materialId}")]
    public string GetPipeMaterial(int materialId)
    {
        var desc = materialsController.GetMaterialDescription(materialId);
        return desc;
    }
```

Comment: Extract the desired code out into its own reusable service that can be injected where needed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could create a new `MaterialsController` directly in  `PipeController` like

```
 var desc = new MaterialsController(_context).GetMaterialDescription(materialId);
```

Or you could use `HttpClient` like

```
[HttpGet("{materialId}")]
public string GetPipeMaterial(int materialId)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44317/api/MaterialDescription/5");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return result;
            }

        }
    return "";
}
```